# How to stop node webkit from stopping on error

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit

I am using node webkit to run a HTML5 app. We are trying to release the app for beta release however whenever there is an error it stops the whole application meaning they lose data and faith in the software. For these users (who aren't testing for reliability) I want to hide or log the errors elsewhere without it stopping the program. I have tried adding the line:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", function(e) { alert(e); });
```

However this makes no difference. What is the best way hide these errors?

Comment: Wouldn't fixing the errors make the app even more reliable? That's the whole point of **beta** software. In fact, you should read the docs on [uncaughtException](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

Comment: Completely agree from a technical point of view, however from a business point of view it is confusing our clients and causing a lot of problems. The errors are all in non application critical code, I still want an exception to be thrown and for the thread to be stopped like in Chrome, only to write the error to a file or elsewhere rather than stop the application just because a third party module hits an unexpected error

Comment: Just `try {} catch ()` those parts then. You'll need to provide some sort of fallback anyway so that your application continues as expected. Only you know that it's *non-critical*